# jarsigner error for maven build using java 1.8

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to build a maven project. However getting below error:

```
 Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Result of /bin/sh -c "cd /Users/rokde/Documents/workspace/mfc/map-coder/coder-web/target/jnlpStandalone && /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/jarsigner -keystore ../../******.jks -storepass ****** -keypass ****** -signedjar /Users/rokde/Documents/workspace/mfc/map-coder/coder-web/target/jnlpStandalone/coder-model-22.07-SNAPSHOT.jar -storetype jks /Users/rokde/Documents/workspace/mfc/map-coder/coder-web/target/jnlpStandalone/unprocessed_coder-model-22.07-SNAPSHOT.jar ******" execution is: '127'.
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.jar.JarSignMojo.signJar(JarSignMojo.java:344)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.jar.JarSignMojo.execute(JarSignMojo.java:241)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.webstart.AbstractBaseJnlpMojo.signJars(AbstractBaseJnlpMojo.java:733)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.webstart.AbstractBaseJnlpMojo.signOrRenameJars(AbstractBaseJnlpMojo.java:609)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.webstart.JnlpDownloadServletMojo.execute(JnlpDownloadServletMojo.java:139)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
```

My env variables:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=/Users/rokde/Downloads/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `JAVA_HOME` is incorrect: verify if `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/jarsigner` exists. AFAIK it only exists in the JDK and not the JRE.

Comment: yes. you are right. but i don't know whats the issue with JAVA_HOME. I've shared my JAVA_HOME value above.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran in to this issue on Mac OS Sierra. For whatever when Maven is trying to sign jars it is trying to use `jarsigner` from `JAVA_HOME/jre/bin`, but there is no `jarsigner` executable in there, it's at `JAVA_HOME/bin`.

Creating a symbolic link to jarsigner in the `JAVA_HOME/jre/bin` directory seemed to have fixed this problem for me going forward.